# discard x-axis label in multi-bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have produced the graph shown below as intended with matplotlib and Pandas except two problems:
I can't get rid of the x axes labels (Year) for the three plots at the top (things I have tried are commented out in the code attached), and I could not centre the y axis label. 
It seem trivial but I can't get it to work.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 12))
for i, crop in enumerate(['Cabbage','Green beans','Potato', 'Wheat']):
    mean_irr_soil[crop].plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[i], title=crop, grid=False)
    axes[i].set_ylim([0, 700])                  # set limit for all y axes
    axes[i].tick_params(axis='x', top='off')    # remove top ticks
    axes[i].tick_params(axis='y', right='off')  # remove right-hand ticks
    axes[i].tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom='off')
    if i is not 0:
        axes[i].legend_.remove()    # all but top graph
    # if i is not 3:
    #     axes[i].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)      # remove axis all together
        # axes[i].tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom='off')
        # axes[i].set_xticklabels([]) # remove x-axis labels
axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.4))
axes[2].set_ylabel('Mean irrigation requirements in mm')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `xlabel` attribute: `ax.set_xlabel("")`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. One more thing, how could I centre the y label?